# generate an Excel file using PHP

Tags: php, excel, web-applications

I'm new with PHP, I'm developping a WEB application that display a table with informations from an SQL server DATA BASE, the problem that I want to add a button to generate an EXCEL file that contains the table displayed? Is that possible?? 
@Ranjit this is the PHP code that displays the table and generate the excel file

edit 1

```
<?php
$ch="";
if(isset($_POST['historique']))
{
    if ((!empty($_POST['Date_de_debut']))&& (!empty($_POST['Date_de_fin']))&&(!empty($_POST['Heure_de_debut']))&&(!empty($_POST['Heure_de_fin'])))
    {
                $ch= "(CONVERT(Datetime, '".$_POST['Date_de_debut']." ".$_POST['Heure_de_debut'].".000',120)) and (CONVERT(Datetime, '".$_POST['Date_de_fin']." ".$_POST['Heure_de_fin'].".000',120))";
        ?>
<table id="tab" border="1">
                <tr>
              <th><font color="red">Date</font></th>
                <th><font color="red">Agent</font></th>
            <th><font color="red">numéro</font></th>    
                </tr>
<?php

$search = " // my query
where operationDate between" .$ch;
$stmt = mssql_query($search);
                             while ($data = mssql_fetch_assoc($stmt))
                             {
                                     ?>
     <tr>
 <td><?php echo utf8_encode ($data['operationDate']);?></td>
 <td><?php echo utf8_encode ($data['fullName']);?></td>
 <td><?php echo utf8_encode ($data['number']);?></td>
                                     </tr>
<?php
     } }

     ?>
        </table>
<?php
}
$output ='';
if(isset($_POST['excel']))
{
    if ((!empty($_POST['Date_de_debut']))&& (!empty($_POST['Date_de_fin']))&&(!empty($_POST['Heure_de_debut']))&&(!empty($_POST['Heure_de_fin'])))
    {
    $rq = "// my query
                                 where operationDate between" ."(CONVERT(Datetime, '".$_POST['Date_de_debut']." ".$_POST['Heure_de_debut'].".000',120)) and (CONVERT(Datetime, '".$_POST['Date_de_fin']." ".$_POST['Heure_de_fin'].".000',120))";
    $res = mssql_query($rq);
  if(mssql_num_rows($res)>0)
  {
    $output.='<table border=1>
            <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Depanneur</th>
                  <th>numéro</th>
              </tr>
              ';
              while ($row=mssql_fetch_array($res))
              {
                $output .='
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["operationDate"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["fullName"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["number"].'</td>
                </tr>';
              }
                            $output .='</table>';
              header("Content-Type: application/xls;charset=UTF-8");
              header("Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=file.xls");

              echo $output;
                            //mssql_close($conn);
}}}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to select the data manually then insert them into the excel sheet, there's php library called PHPEXCEL you can use it.

See this
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-to-excel-in-php-with-my-sql/

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice packages out there to generate excel files such as
[Box Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) and [PHP Spreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The documentation of both packages is very clear any you will be generating excel files within minutes of browsing through documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,

It is possible. You can follow this

1) Connect to database:

2) Define a filename of excel

```
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word) 
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character 
$fp = fopen('database.xls', "w"); 
$schema_insert = ""; 
$schema_insert_rows = ""; 
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
```

Sources - http://www.anillabs.com/2010/03/how-to-create-excel-file-with-mysql-data-using-php-code/

Comment: i'm already connected to the database as the informations are displayed on the screen when i click on the button "show", need i to reconnect to export the informations on the excel file?? need i to excute the query second time and fetch the informations one more time to storage them on the excel file?? or i have to pass them directly with the first query?

PS : i'm using MICROSOFT SQL SERVER

Comment: i did generate an excel file , but the problem is that the file does not generate only the table, it generates the hole HTML page even the buttons and the edit text .

Comment: is too long, how can i write it in a comment??

Comment: Can you remove the html from the file. Because, there is no need of Html in that file.